# Copy app error: "The open file ulimit level is too low, please increase it otherwise changes will not be detected properly"

Tags: ulimit, copy.com

When using [Copy](https://www.copy.com/home/), I get this error:

```
Error: "The open file ulimit level is too low, please increase it otherwise changes will not be detected properly"
```

The application stops syncing when it appears, why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You will have to be more specific.

Comment: @psusi: Thanks for your comment. I made the question more clear. I just wish to contribute to askubuntu writing this answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Create file `/etc/sysctl.d/60-copy.conf`

2) Open that file and write:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 20000
fs.file-max = 800000
```

3) Save the file and exit

4) Go to the terminal and apply those settings by typing:

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/60-copy.conf
```

5) Launch the Copy app again and it should work.

Comment: I don't know what this app is since the link you gave is dead and gone. But if you are going to suggest adding files to /etc/sysctl.d, please read the README in that directory first. :)

Comment: @chaskes: Thanks for your comment. This is app is competing against Dropbox. For more information, please see the app's tag wiki.

Comment: For some reason this only worked for me *once*. After that I tried increasing the limits even 100 times more than this and I couldn't get the CopyAgent to start.